# Test site speed

Tags: cdn, benchmark, network-speed

I am test driving an Akmai CDN architecture and before committing to buy, I would like to gauge the real performance gain from the acceleration feature.

What would be the best MO for doing speed tests from different locations around the world?

I would like to test the page load speed and not just the server response time.
I would like to test speed from as many edge locations as possible.

I do not mind a paid service as well, if it is optimal.

Thank you!

Comment: Gomez, Websitepulse or pingdom.

Comment: this is exactly what [watchmouse.com](http://www.watchmouse.com) provide. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tools I've used to gauage site speed have been the following

Pingdom's Load Time test; http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ and Pingdom in general as a service.

Blitz.io; http://blitz.io/

And finally Load Impact (I can't attach another URL, .com)

They all can provide multi location checks and both have flavours of free/paid tests.